# Connecting to Hadoop from Java app using SSH

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, ssh, hdfs

I'm trying to connect to remote hadoop cluster, which isn't accessible just through HDFS. Right now it is being used in that way: user connects to Jump box through SSH (e.g. ssh user@somejumboxhost.com), then from jump box server we do connect to hadoop also with ssh (e.g. ssh user@realhadoopcluster1.com). What I'm trying to do is to access files from my Scala/Java application using HDFS client. Now I'm feeling like in Matrix - "I must go deeper" and don't know how to reach the server.

May be someone had similar experience? Right now I'm trying to connect to first server with SSH client from my app, but then I don't know how to call the HDFS client.

Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think  of something like this . There is "ganymed-ssh2" api which helps you to connect to some server using ssh and run unix command from there. Using this you can connect to your jumo box.

And from there you can run command as " ssh  user@realhadoopcluster1.com hadoop fs somthing"

As we can run commands with ssh like this.

From your jump box, setup a password less ssh to your hadoopcluster machine. or you can use sshpass with password.

You can visit following link to check how to use this api:

http://souravgulati.webs.com/apps/forums/topics/show/8116298-how-to-execute-unix-command-from-java-

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I've end up with something similar, I was using scala-ssh lib, but then just decided to put the file I need to access in a better place, so it would be easier to get.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is implemented in Java, so you could just run the Hadoop cluster directly from your application. Use Java RMI if it's a remote cluster. This extra pipework you're trying to do makes no sense.